# ShopifyAPI - Application Charge with Activation

Tags: shopify

Here is the workflow of how the app will (hopefully we can do this) flow:

1. Customer installs App (Gets 7 Day Free Trial)
2. After the Free Trial, rather than using Recurring Charges we want to bill the customer for every time they 'Create A New Product' through our app.

**Question:** We just want to bill for each time the shop owner plans to create the product using our app, and **not** using a time interval such as 1 month, or 1 year etc. Can we still do this using the Recurring Billing or do we need to use the One-Time billing options?

I tried to test it locally but I got and error trying the confirmation_url:

*Your plan 'development' cannot be charged through the API.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the one-time billing for this. Once 7 days ticks by the clock in your app, the next time a product is created, you create a one time charge. You're really treading in shark infested waters doing this though. What happens if a merchant creates a second product before they accept the first charge you've created? You can only have single one time charge I think... until it is accepted, you'd probably be trying to create them to no avail. And since it can take a minute for a product created in Shopify to show up in your App, that gives them a minute to create a second or third product. So then they try to access your App with 3 products created and one onetime charge. Huh? You try it.. see what happens. Maybe it'll all work out.

Comment: What if I use a Recurring charge with null values for trials_days of 0 and trial_ends_on as null?

Comment: Oh, is there a way to test this while in development?

Comment: I think we can setup an extra field in our app that looks at the applicataion_charge_id that is associated with our internal product. Unless the 'status' is 'activated' they cannot create a new product through our system.